# Is there a way to specify what methods a library contains in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a CMake project where I'm using some options to control what the final library actually implements. Something like this (in pseudo-code):

```
// CMakeLists.txt
option(ADD_BAR "Include the bar methods" ON)
configure_file(...)
add_library(foo SHARED foo.cpp)

// foo.cpp
void doFoo(){
  ...
}
#ifdef ADD_BAR
void bar(){
  ...
}
#endif
```

Then, I have other targets that link against this library. Is there a way in CMake I can detect whether `bar()` exists in the final `libfoo.so` or that this target was compiled with this option disabled? Basically, I'd like to propagate the information about how the library was compiled (e.g. with what enabled options) so I can skip downstream targets that consume it but need unsupported features.

Comment: Move `ADD_BAR` to a header and use `#ifdef ADD_BAR`  in consumers code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's have a macro that produces a bit of code that checks whether a symbol was defined, and adds a relevant macro definition for the compiler:

```
macro (add_definition_if_var symbol)
  if (${symbol})
    add_compile_definitions (${symbol})
  endif ()
endmacro ()
```

Then, it's as easy as:

```
option (ADD_BAR "Include the bar methods" ON)
add_definition_if_var (ADD_BAR)
```

And, if `ADD_BAR` was set to ON, the `ADD_BAR` macro will be defined within your library project :)

If you have many such options, you could do it all in one go:

```
function (defining_option var description state)
  option (${var} "${description}" ${state})
  if (${var})
    add_compile_definitions (${var})
  endif ()
endfunction ()


defining_option (ADD_BAR "Include the bar methods" ON)
defining_option (ADD_FROB "Frobnicate" OFF)
```